# Why does the XCode debugger output not match what I expect, when interrogating UIButton values?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

This screenshot explains it all: 
  [image]

The screenshot shows the debugger reporting buttonType as 2 but the console showing button type = 0.  The same variable is being shown in the debugger and the console.  Any idea how this mismatch happens?

```
(gdb) po ((UIButton *)control).buttonType
```

There is no member named buttonType.

As requested:

```
    NSLog(@"################ CALL OUT ACCESSORY TAPPED: set pinColor to RED in call out accessory tapped");
    NSLog(@"################ CALL OUT ACCESSORY TAPPED: UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure = %d",UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure);
    NSLog(@"################ CALL OUT ACCESSORY TAPPED: control button type = %d", ((UIButton *)control).buttonType);

    if (((UIButton *)control).buttonType == 2) {
        NSLog(@" ############# CALL OUT ACCESSORY TAPPED: in buttonType = disclosure");
        leftCallOutButton.available = YES;
    }
```

The if statements evaluates to false!! Trying to understand why if buttonType is being reported as 2 (and if fact is created with type 2 )

as request by Mike:

```
(gdb) p (int) [((UIButton *)control) buttonType]
$1 = 0
2009-12-31 14:04:26.821 iParkNow![4432:207] ################ CALL OUT ACCESSORY TAPPED: control button type = 0
(gdb) p (int) [((UIButton *)control) buttonType]
```

Ok, so this makes more sense.  The question now is why is the buttonType being changed from 2 to 0?  Its created with buttonType 2 and somehow gets changed to 0.  Any ideas??

Comment: @ennuikiller: Can you give us the code from the `NSLog()` call which outputs "UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure = 2" through the `NSLog()` call which outputs "control button type = 0," including both those lines? That might help a bit.

Comment: @John, posted as per your request.

Comment: @ennuikiller: Did you try running my revised command? Can you post the results?

Comment: @ennuikiller, I think you meant me. The command is `p (int) [((UIButton *)control) buttonType]`

Comment: @ennuikiller: Thank you. Very interesting, at first I thought I spotted it, then I realized my error. I find it interesting that `po ((UIButton *)control).buttonType` prints no such member found when (at your breakpoint) you've already performed the exact same line of code. What about `po control`? Admittedly, this will be a LOT of extraneous data, but it might give more insight.

Comment: @Mike:  ok it looks like the debugger is reporting correctly.  btw, do you know why control is not showing up in the variable list?

Comment: @enniukiller: OK, that latest edit confirms my suspicions. Are you 100% positive that the UIButton instance you're dealing with here is in fact the one you think it is? Are there other properties you can check to validate that it really is the button you're expecting?

Comment: @john, please send @Mike's suggestion.  It prints out the integer instead of an object.

Comment: Correct, and it's printing `0`, which is the custom button type. You're expecting a `2` here (the disclosure type), and not getting it. Hence my question of are you 100% sure that the button you're dealing with in this code really is the button you're expecting, and if it is, is there any code anywhere else which might have changed your `buttonType`?

Comment: Dying of curiosity, as you've accepted Mike's answer: What was the final resolution, outside of determining that the buttonType really was 0?

Comment: @john, no resolution yet...as you said I'll to go back and make sure the control I'm looking at has buttonType 2.  I'm pretty certain to I created it with that type so I'll have to see where it was modified!....makes me wish I've taken up functional programming !

Comment: I hope you're able to figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_buttonFlags is a private instance struct. You should not worry about it. The only thing that is "guaranteed" to work as you expect is the public API - implementation details are subject to change.

(As a side-note, a variable prefaced with _ is usually a private instance variable)

In your case, try `p (int) [((UIButton *)control) buttonType]`.

You can also consider creating a breakpoint action to log whatever you want at a breakpoint you set. See http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/200-Managing_Program_Execution/program_execution.html for more details.

Comment: ok, then how do I check the value of buttonType in the debugger?

Comment: @Mike, please the result of print object in my question.  Its not able to resolve that variable.